# cannot save a record using has many through in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I and not able to find why the record cannot be saved into the database...Help me find what I did wrong in my models and controllers.

### User.rb

```
has_many :interested_users_lists
has_many :interested_posts, through: :interested_users_lists
accepts_nested_attributes_for :interested_users_lists, :interested_posts
```

...etc

### InterestedUsersList.rb

```
class InterestedUsersList < ApplicationRecord
    # belongs_to :post
    # belongs_to :users 
    belongs_to :interested_post, class_name: 'Post'    
    belongs_to :interested_user, class_name: 'User' 
end
```

### Post.rb

```
belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_id", touch: true
has_many :interested_users_lists, dependent: :destroy
has_many :interested_users, through: :interested_users_lists
accepts_nested_attributes_for :interested_users_lists, :interested_users
```

etc...
method I used:

```
  # add interested user
  def add_interested_user(user)
   puts "this is user id:  #{user.id} "
   interestedUser = self.interested_users_lists.build(user_id: user.id)
   interestedUser.save
   puts "this is #{interested_users_lists.first.user_id} "
  end
```

### Migration file

```
class CreateInterestedUsersLists < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :interested_users_lists do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :post_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

### posts_controller.rb

```
def interested
 @post.add_interested_user(current_user) #cannot be saved...
end
...
private
 def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:subject, :price, :category, :street_address, :city, :state, :zip, :condition, :payment_method, :content, post_attachments_attributes: [:id, :post_id, :avatar], 
                                interested_users_lists_attributes: [:id, :post_id, :user_id])
end
```

development log

```
  Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? ORDER BY "posts"."created_at" DESC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
this is user id:  2

   **(0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction** _why???_

  InterestedUsersList Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "interested_users_lists".* FROM "interested_users_lists" WHERE "interested_users_lists"."post_id" = ?  [["post_id", 1]]
this is 2
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/posts/2
Completed 302 Found in 77ms (ActiveRecord: 4.9ms)


Started GET "/users/posts/2" for ::1 at 2016-12-27 03:04:33 -0800
```

Comment: Use save! on your method and you'll get a traceback. Post it here if you still didn't get an idea how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Change this method You don't need to save a through record

```
# add interested user
def add_interested_user(user)
  self.interested_users << user
end
```

Comment: It's good practice to use self if you are assigning the data to object you can omit self if you are reading the data

Comment: @DeepakMahakale this is what I got in return... I don't think this works.. `Validation failed: Password can't be blank, Password is too short (minimum is 8 characters)
Application Frames All Frames
Post#add_interested_user
app/models/post.rb, line 182
PostsController#interested
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb, line 141
`